# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 2) for Tensor 'labels:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am relatively new to python and machine learning. When I run this code, it comes up with this value error. Unfortunately, I cannot seen to be able to reshape the input to match both shapes. I have tried to change the shape of the label to (None, None, 2) but when I run it, train cost come up as 'nan'. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import csv  
import tensorflow as tf  
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd   
import urllib.request as request  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/train_data.csv", sep=',', header = None)  
test_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/test_data.csv", sep=',', header = None)  

X_train = np.asarray(train_data)  
X_test = np.asarray(test_data)  

train_label = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/train_label.csv", sep=',', header = None)  
test_label = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/test_label.csv", sep=',', header = None)  

y_train = np.asarray(train_label)  
y_test = np.asarray(test_label)  

labels_train = (np.arange(2) == y_train[:,None]).astype(np.float32)  
labels_test = (np.arange(2) == y_test[:,None]).astype(np.float32)  

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]), name='inputs')
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='labels')

hid1_size = 128   
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hid1_size, X_train.shape[1]], stddev=0.01), name='w1')  
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=(hid1_size, 1)), name='b1')  
y1 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(w1, tf.transpose(inputs)), b1)),  keep_prob=0.5)

hid2_size = 256  
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hid2_size, hid1_size], stddev=0.01), name='w2')  
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=(hid2_size, 1)), name='b2')  
y2 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(w2, y1), b2)), keep_prob=0.5)  

wo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, hid2_size], stddev=0.01), name='wo')  
bo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name='bo')  
yo = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(wo, y2), bo))  

lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(), name='learning_rate')  
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=yo, labels=label))  
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)  

pred = tf.nn.softmax(yo)  
pred_label = tf.argmax(pred, 1)  
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(label, 1))  
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))  

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  

config = tf.ConfigProto()  
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)  
sess.run(init)  

for learning_rate in [0.05, 0.01]:  
    for epoch in range(50):  
        avg_cost = 0.0  
        for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):  
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={lr:learning_rate,  
                                                          inputs: X_train[i, None],  
                                                          label: labels_train[i, None]})  
            avg_cost += c  
        avg_cost /= X_train.shape[0]  
        if epoch % 10 == 0:  
            print("Epoch: {:3d}    Train Cost: {:.4f}".format(epoch, avg_cost))  

acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={inputs: X_train, label: labels_train})
print("Train accuracy: {:3.2f}%".format(acc_train*100.0))

acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={inputs: X_test, label: labels_test})
print("Test accuracy:  {:3.2f}%".format(acc_test*100.0))

sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that while your `labels` placeholder requires an array of shape `(None, 2)`, you are passing one with a shape of `(1, 1, 2)`

This is done in the line where you run your Session (`sess.run()`) and more specifically in the `feed_dict` where you are passing the `labels_train[i, None]` to the placeholder `labels`.

From your code I can't tell what exactly you are trying to do with your labels, but a simple reshape should do the trick:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={lr:learning_rate,  
                                              inputs: X_train[i, None],  
                                              label: labels_train[i, None].reshape(-1, 2)})
```

This is far from the *optimal* solution the problem; think of it as a workaround, till you get to better acquainted with python and tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately when I run the updated code, the train cost still comes up as 'nan'.

Comment: Try printing the cost of the model (`c`) in each epoch, to see if it is *nan* in every epoch or if something else is  causing this.

Comment: Thanks but it is nan in every epoch. I am unsure what to do. Also, could you please explain why you have reshaped labels_train to (-1, 2), specifically why you chose -1? Much appreciated.

Comment: When it says `(?, 2)` it means that your cost function is expecting a 2-dimensional array. The second dimension should have a size of 2, while the first can have any shape it wants. When you reshape an array you need the product of the dimensions to stay the same. So let's say you reshape to `(-1, 2)` you tell it to make it so that the second dimension has a size of 2 and to calculate the size of the first on its own. Now for the nan part, I don't think that it has to do with the shapes, rather than your data. I suggest you try a different example till you get better acquainted with tensorflow